# Normal maps not importing in unity using Khronos GLTF importer

Tags: gltf

When I import a gltf model that uses a normal map I get this error:

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Stream has been closed'. System.IO.FileStream.get_Length () (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) UnityGLTF.GLTFSceneImporter+<ConstructUnityTexture>d__58.MoveNext () (at Assets/UnityGLTF/Scripts/GLTFSceneImporter.cs:643)
```

The export is done is using this tool: https://github.com/facebookincubator/FBX2glTF
I ran the gltf files through khronos gltf validator and got a successful validation.

Sample model https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/sourceModels/Avocado

The importer works fine if the object doesn't have any normal maps in it.

Comment: This question is not for Unity but for the GLTF community.

Comment: I've added gltf tag here as well

Comment: If the model passes the official validation, and works on at least one viewer (try https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) then I would recommend filing a bug on the importer: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF **EDIT:** Or given that this is an official sample model failing, I would definitely file a bug. :)

Comment: Yep it's working on a different gltf  web viewer and UniGltf (unity scene importer) as well. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF/issues/582 reported an issue on their github.

Answer (score 1):

Since UnityGLTF has some open issues and is not actively maintained at the moment, I'd suggest the following:

1. Try an alternative. [glTFast](https://github.com/atteneder/glTFast) in particular supports normal maps, has better performance (disclaimer: I'm the main developer) and more features.
2. If you need to stick with UnityGLTF, try [prefrontal cortex's fork](https://github.com/prefrontalcortex/UnityGLTF), which has many improvements.